# Single Layer Perceptron with three classes

Tags: dataset, perceptron

I need some help with a single layered perceptron with multiple classes.

What I need to do is classify a dataset with three different classes, by now I just learnt how to do it with two classes, so I have no really a good clue how to do it with three.

The dataset have three different classes: Iris-setosa, Iris-versicolor and Iris-versicolor.

The url with the dataset and the information is in :  http://ftp.ics.uci.edu/pub/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data.

I really appreciate any help anyone can give to me.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Let's say, we have 3 classes:

- Red
- Blue
- Green

Now we build 3 classifiers

- red v/s blue and green combined
- blue v/s red and green combined
- green v/s red and blue combined

This gives us 3 models.

For a new point, we classify it according to the classifier that gives us the largest distance from the 3 hyperplanes for the new point.

This strategy is called "one vs all", and you can read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification).

Answer (score 0):

We cannot classify a dataset with 3 classes using just one perceptron. you need to use a multilayer perceptron and have 3 output nodes for the three different classes,

1. Iris-Setosa
2. Iris-Versicolor
3. Iris-Virginica

We use softmax activation function for multi-class classification problems where class membership is required on more than two class labels.

softmax is given by the formula,
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1K7F.png